# Tatamibari: an introduction

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sup>This is an entry for [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #44: Introduce a new grid deduction genre to the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7080)</sup>

---

This is a Tatamibari puzzle, where you divide the grid into rectangles and squares.

Rules taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatamibari#Rules):

- Every partition must contain exactly one symbol in it.
- A + symbol must be contained in a square.
- A | symbol must be contained in a rectangle with a greater height than width.
- A - symbol must be contained in a rectangle with a greater width than height.
- Four pieces may never share the same corner.

An example puzzle and its solution:

[image: example puzzle]

[image: example solution]

Now, solve this puzzle:

[image: the real puzzle - see CSV file below]

Here is the puzzle in a [playable form](https://puzz.link/p?tatamibari/10/10/o1t2g2k22h1r13r3h33k1g3t2o). The link leads to a puzz.link editor (which has a timer, if you care about that).

First answer with a full logical solution path gets the checkmark.

CSV version:

```
,,,,,,,,,|
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,-,,-,,,
,,-,-,,,|,,,
,,,,,,,,,|
+,,,,,,,,,
,,,+,,,+,+,,
,,,|,,+,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
-,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic deductions:

> [image]

Now, we ask:

> Which room touches the upper left corner? It turns out only one of the clues can reach there -- the clue in row 3, column 5.
>  [image]

And a similar question is helpful again:

> Which room goes in row 4, column 1? Only one clue works there. And what about row 1, column 7? The `─` clue just underneath it *must* be the one to use that cell -- which requires us to cram the rooms in the top section together.
>
>  [image]

A similar process lets us fill up the left column:

> R9C1 can only be reached by the clue below it, which fixes that as a 2×3 rectangle. Then R8C1 must be part of the square above it, and the left column is complete.
>
>  At the same time, we can use reachability on a bunch of cells in the bottom row, and fill up the bottom as well.
>  [image]

And similar arguments work to finish off the puzzle. The solution is:

> [image]

Comment: What tool/website do you use to solve these puzzles?

Comment: @daw I use puzz.link! It's a very nice website that has interfaces for both constructing and solving puzzles. There's a link to the puzz.link interface in the original question.